# Need inputs on troubleshooting Runtime.getRuntime.exec() on Low Memory System ?

Tags: java, linux, tomcat6

I our web application we are using Process myProcess = Runtime.getRuntime.exec(cmd).
It is currently deployed using Tomcat hosted on Ubuntu Linux.

This application works fine on my development machine (Core2 duo ,2GB RAM OS:UBUNTU 11.04).

However when i host the same on Virtual Server (1GB RAM,Xeon processor) the Runtime.getRuntime.exec(cmd) call fails. It is unable to create the sub process.

The same  sub process is created and we got the expected output on my development machine.

In the application we are calling the java class in the servlet which is deployed in the tomcat is executing well and output is fine. below is code snippet of the same.

```
from the servlet
uploadservlet.java
+-----------+   
CalculateDuration dur=new CalculateDuration();
Map<String, Integer> durationmap=dur.conversion(al);
+-------------+

Caclulateduration.java
+------------------+
{
     conversion(ArrayList<String> b)
     {

      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
          sb.append( "hello.o"); /* Name of the sample executable */         
       ...

          Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(sb.toString() ); //struck at this line.subprocess not created on my vps system 

      ...

          +------------------+
```

The Standalone Caclulateduration.java runs on the Virtual Server.

Could this issue be caused becuase insufficient physical memory (leading to getRunTime failing) on the Virtual Server or i am missing some thing here. Any tools,commands or methods to root cause this
problem.

Your inputs are appreciated !

Comment: First you should accept answer in your other questions...

Answer (score 0):

Java's `Runtime.exec()` before 1.7 uses `fork()/exec()` to spawn a process. Forking means duplicating the current process, which being a Java application is probably huge. To be able to fork() an application, you need to have enough **virtual** address space available. How much is enough depends on your OS's memory overcommit settings.

To avoid all this trouble, Java 1.7 (Sun/OpenJDK/...) supports `vfork()/exec()` and `posix_spawn()`. `posix_spawn()` directly spawns a new process, while `vfork()` shares memory between parent and child until the imminent `execve()`, so they shouldn't require as much virtual address space to work.

Comment: ok Alvin thanks for gave valuable information. Actually i don't know vfork().can u give sample code for how to work with vfork() in java.and also i will provide what is the free memory availabe....

Comment: Thanks to Alvin.finally i got the solution.i think there is a problem with the executable path. previously i gave the executablepath in different manner.at that time it is unable to create the subprocess. now i changed to in this manner,      String[] cmd= {"/ffmpeg_git_v2/ffmpeg/ffmpeg", "-i", filename};process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd) in this way i executed the ffmpeg.exe file on my vps system.now its working.

Comment: I can't see the rest of your code, but you should ensure that you are consuming the streams resulting from that Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...) call.  I've run into many bizarre errors from not doing so.